# 'null' file in Windows32 directory, with dir command outcome

Tags: sql-server, windows

I try to find out what can be a cause of this - the file without extension, called null, is in our System32 directory. It looks like inside there is an outcome of 'dir' command. Something is gathering information from directory every 15 minute and write to a file. It's not a scheduler task. It's only on SQL Servers. Can you think of any mechanism that can trigger it?

Comment: Probably a badly written cmd batch running from a scheduled task

Comment: Try searching the drive for a batch file with the text `> null`; it should be `> nul` instead.